# QGIS 3.2 - How do I only display only one of my overlapping rasters at a time?

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3

I have a series of overlapping rasters and I only want one to display at a time so that the borders of neighbouring rasters are not obscuring anything on the centre raster. Is there a way to tell QGIS to only display the centre-most raster? Preferably this would only occur at a certain scale so one can still see the full extents of the raster when zoomed out.